# Avoid using custom animations when switching navigation stacks in BottomNavigationView and navigation component?

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I have a `BottomNavigationView` that uses  navigation component and it is configured using `bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(this.navHostFragment.navController)`

It has two items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:title="@string/tab1title" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:title="@string/tab2title" />
</menu>
```

The navigation graph is defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/tab1">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/tab1"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/tab2"/>
</navigation>
```

Navigation inside `tab1` and `tab2` works by stacking fragments that are presented using actions, and these actions have custom animations:

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/open_fragment_1"
        app:destination="@id/fragment1"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
```

With this setup I have two navigation stacks that get properly saved and restored when switching tabs.

The problem is that when I navigate from one tab to the other while there are fragments stacked in any of the navigation stacks the custom animations defined in the `action` used to present the top fragment will be used instead of using the default animations that should be used when switching tabs. For example, if `fragment1` is presented in `tab1` and the user goes from `tab2` to `tab1` there will be a slide in animation because that's what's defined in `open_fragment_1`.

I tried defining my own animations in `R.animator` with all the `nav_default_*` defined, but these only work for the root fragments of `tab1` and `tab2`.

How can I achieve the right behavior?

Edit: this seems to be a bug -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194113170